# New column type with minipage and itemize inserts additional vertical whitespace in each row

Tags: tables, spacing, minipage

I have the following LaTeX code

```
\newcolumntype{K}{>{\begin{minipage}[b]{21em}\begin{itemize}}c<{\end{itemize}\end{minipage}}}
%\newcolumntype{K}{>{\begin{minipage}[t]{21em}\begin{itemize}}c<{\end{itemize}\end{minipage}}}

\begin{tabular}{K K}\hline
  \item Item 1-1   &  \item Item 1-2  \tabularnewline\hline
  \item Item 2-1   &  \item Item 2-2  \tabularnewline\hline
  \item Item 3-1   &  \item Item 3-2  \tabularnewline\hline
  \item Item 4-1   &  \item Item 4-2  \tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}
```

The horizontal lines are only for instructive purpose. If the minipage has the align specifier "b" or "c" the rows of the table are typesetted with no additional vertical space, i.e. the horizontal lines between the rows of the table are directly attached to the box of the minipage.

But I want the items to be align at the top. However, if I change the alignment specifier to "t" (uncomment the 2nd line), then some additional vertical space is suddenly inserted at the top of each row.

Why? And how do I prevent that?

Comment: why use a minipage in a c column rather than a `p` column (which is a top aligned parbox already)?

Comment: Two reasons: (1) Minipage sets `\@minipagetrue` which removes some extra vertical space before and after the itemize-environment. At the end (without the horizontal rules) each column of the table should like like *one* itemized list and not like a stack of separated lists. Essentially, I need two bullet-list side-by-side with horizontal adjustment of particular entries in both lists.
(2) With column specifier p (and enabling `\@minipagetrue` manually) I have the same problem with top-aligned minipages. I.e. parboxes also insert this strange gap at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, ragged2e}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{ >{\RaggedRight\compress\itemize}p{#1}<{\enditemize}}
\newcommand*{\mcbf}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{table with special column}
    \label{5.1}
    \centering
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,%wide=0pt,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  after=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\partopsep\relax}
                  }
 \begin{tabular}{*{2}{K{12em}}}
                                                        \hline
  \item Item 1-1   &  \item Item 1-2 go here  \tabularnewline   \hline
  \item Item 2-1   &  \item Item 2-2 go here  \tabularnewline   \hline
  \item Item 3-1   &  \item Item 3-2 go here  \tabularnewline   \hline
  \item Item 4-1   &  \item Item 4-2 go here  \tabularnewline   \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```